Java Card Eclipse Plugin for Java Card 3.0.5 cannot create any applets (due to JAXBException)
Prior to this I was developing Java Card applets using Eclipse and JavaCard Plugin for Eclipse.
However when I tried to swith to Java Card 3.0.x, I've installed the realted runtime java_card_devkit_tools-bin-v24.0-b_57-20-FEB-2024.zip plus the related eclipse plugin java_card_devkit_eclipse_plugin-bin-v24.0-b_50-20-FEB-2024downloaded from oracel web-site.
When I tried to create new Java card applet, at the last step the java card project wizard shows a pop-up error message which prompts:

An error occuered while creating the Java Card project.
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException


According to Q&A in StackOverflow this is due to removal of JAXB from Java Runtime in newer version and since plugin/eclipse is looking for that it will cause errors.
I've searched through lots of questions and answers in the SO, however as a fix they were asked developers to ask some lines into their source to fix issues (like inside Spring Application) or add some dependencies to their projects using Maven/Gradle build systems.
However, since the error is happening inside internal IDE Application itself, I cannot change anything to fix this since I have no access to Eclipse or Java Card Plugin source codes to fix this.
Some suggested to install eclipse-ee4j for Eclipse. I've downloaded that but it contained some JAR files and I don't know how to add it to Eclipse to overcome this issue.
I should mention again that Java Card Project is not created due to Create New Project wizard exception in Eclipse so I cannot change anything inside application source (since there is no source yet to modify).
Update:
Eclipse Version:
Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
Build id: 20240307-1437
The Log Error output is like this:
eclipse.buildId=4.31.0.20240307-1200
java.version=18.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data file:/C:/Users/Eve/eclipse-workspace/
org.eclipse.core.resources
Error
4
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.ResourceDeltaProcessor.visit(ResourceDeltaProcessor.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:61)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.Activator$1.resourceChanged(Activator.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2462)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2473)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:6082)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core_1.0.0.201505220623
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 16 more

Here is the error log captured from Eclipse log file:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2024-05-08 14:07:42.006
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.ResourceDeltaProcessor.visit(ResourceDeltaProcessor.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:61)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.Activator$1.resourceChanged(Activator.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2462)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2473)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:6082)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core_1.0.0.201505220623
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 16 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 10001 2024-05-08 14:07:42.065
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard.performFinish(NewElementWizard.java:133)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.wizards.project.NewJCDKProjectWizard.performFinish(NewJCDKProjectWizard.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewWizardDropDownAction.run(NewWizardDropDownAction.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.wizards.project.pages.NewJavaCardProjectWizardPageTwo.performFinish(NewJavaCardProjectWizardPageTwo.java:499)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.wizards.project.NewJCDKProjectWizard.finishPage(NewJCDKProjectWizard.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard.lambda$1(NewElementWizard.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2448)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2473)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:6082)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core_1.0.0.201505220623
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.wizards.project.pages.NewJavaCardProjectWizardPageTwo.performFinish(NewJavaCardProjectWizardPageTwo.java:499)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.wizards.project.NewJCDKProjectWizard.finishPage(NewJCDKProjectWizard.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard.lambda$1(NewElementWizard.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2448)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2473)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:6082)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core_1.0.0.201505220623
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2024-05-08 14:07:42.163
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.ResourceDeltaProcessor.visit(ResourceDeltaProcessor.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:61)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.Activator$1.resourceChanged(Activator.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core_1.0.0.201505220623
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 14 more

[Update] 2024-May-05
The same issue was faced using the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers
I also Included the log for that as well:
eclipse.buildId=4.31.0.20240307-1200
java.version=17.0.10
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Users/E/eclipse-workspace305/

org.eclipse.core.resources
Error
Sat May 11 12:04:06 GMT+03:30 2024
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.ResourceDeltaProcessor.visit(ResourceDeltaProcessor.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:61)
    at com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core.Activator$1.resourceChanged(Activator.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.oracle.javacard.jcdk.core_1.0.0.201505220623
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 14 more


Eclipse 2020-12 is more than three years and 13 releases behind. Pleas upgrade and when asking, make sure your issue is reproducible with the current version.

@howlger I've also tried with latest version Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0), Build id: 20240307-1437

Please show the complete message: go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

@howlger I already copied the log from .log file. I also include log from Error Log window as well for your reference.

You have the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product), but the JavaCard Plugin seems to be for the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

@howlger Interesting. How did you know Java Card Plugin requires Eclipse for Enterprise Java Developers? I will try that however the issue raised here seems to be related to JAXB which seems to be part of Java Run-Time in older versions like JRE 8 but it was removed since JRE 9 or JRE 10 (if I'm not mistaking). So I doubt that changing Eclipse build/flavor change the situation about the main issue which is the missing JAXB.

Yes, javax.xml.bind was removed in Java 11, but if I know correctly, the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers includes it via a plugin. Please try it and let us know if it works.

@howlger I also tried with Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers but the same problem persist. I've included the log for that as well.

I see. Please try to put the following JAR in your dropins folder: https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20201118194144/repository/plugins/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar

@howlger It did not make any changes. I've put the .jar file inside dropins folder. Exactly the same error with the same error logs showed up again.

javax.xml.bind requires javax.xml, javax.xml.stream and javax.activation. Please download them and put them also in the dropins folder.

It gets a bit complicated with Oracle and Javacard. The documentation is always a bit lacking or outdated. So the documentation for 3.0.5 doesn't really specify versions on things expect Java, which it wants at Java 7 or Java 8.
I use jcardsim and ant-javacard instead of the Oracle and Eclipse setup for my Javacard stuff so I haven't tested this myself though but given that the minimum required JDK for Eclipse 2020-12 is JDK 11 and for 2024-03 is JDK 17 I doubt they'll work properly due to how different things are in JDK 11 vs JDK 8.
Eclipse 2020-06 is that last one to support running with JDK 8 so that one might work and would be the latest one to do so.
As a footnote, the documentation for 3.1 specifies that they have tested it with Eclipse Neon, Oxygen or Photon, which are all very much older versions of Eclipse. 3.1 is meant to be supported through JDK 11 though but given they only tested Java 8 based Eclipse versions with it I suspect this is part of that problem. But you might need to go all the way to Photon to make this work.
